# How to distinguish xlsx and docx files from zip archives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, file

I have a use case where I need to know the file type of a file to identify and blacklist the executables(exe,installers etc), archive files(zip, rar etc.). Therefore relying on the extension is not enough for me as the extension of a file can be changed but the file property will remain the same. I tried using the linux command:

```
file --b filename
```

The above solution is working perfectly with all the file types except the .xlsx and .docx file because the command is giving the following for the .xlsx and .docx

> Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

And because of this I end up blacklisting the .xlsx and .docx file as well.

Can anybody suggest me a way to get the file type without using the extension that works for the xlsx and docx as well.

Comment: `xlsx` files and `zip` files have **exactly the same file structure**!!! The *only* difference is the extension name! Don't believe me? - Rename the file, and open it. So no, there is no way to distinguish between these particular "file types" other than looking at the extension.

Comment: Anyway, the concept you are looking at here is *reading the file's MIME-TYPE*. There are [various libraries](https://github.com/mime-types/ruby-mime-types) that do this; you don't need to make an external system call.

Comment: What @TomLord said. These files adhere to [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).  *"[OOXML] is a zipped, XML-based file format developed by Microsoft for representing spreadsheets, charts, presentations and word processing documents."* This format which has been standardized to allow for reading and writing for these document types beyond Microsoft. Prior to this standard microsoft used things like `xls` and `doc` which were proprietary binary formats making it more difficult to share files with non-microsoft users.

Comment: Appropriate MIME Types can be found [Here](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Mimemagic Gem](https://github.com/minad/mimemagic) and added custom magic(as it is called by the Gem) to identify xlsx, docx, and pptx file format. Also this does not relies on the file extension.

Following are the list of magic that I added:

```
[['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.custom', [[0, "PK\x03\x04", [[30, '_rels/.rels', [[0..5000, 'word/']]]]]]],
['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.custom', [[0, "PK\003\004", [[30, '_rels/.rels', [[0..5000, 'xl/']]]]]]],
['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.custom', [[0, "PK\003\004", [[30, '_rels/.rels', [[0..5000, 'ppt/']]]]]]],['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.custom', [[0, "PK\x03\x04", [[30, 'word/']]]]],
['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.custom', [[0, "PK\003\004", [[30, 'xl/']]]]],
['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.custom', [[0, "PK\003\004", [[30, 'ppt/']]]]]].each do |magic|
  MimeMagic.add(magic[0], magic: magic[1])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your `file` command (or its *magic* file).

Recent versions do recognize [MSOOXML](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/msooxml) files:

```
$ file -b test.docx
Microsoft Word 2007+

$ file --version
file-5.32
```

Comment: The file that you shared helped me a lot in finding the answer. Also there was a limitation on upgrading the file command as it was on its latest version available for RHEL7(OS on which the app is hosted). So I could not use this approach, so went ahead with Mimemagic.